# To find a linear transformation such that $T^{2}( v) = -v $

Tags: linear-algebra

Question is to find a linear transformation from $R^{2}$ to $R^{2}$ such that $T^{2}( v) = -v $ for all v .I used hit and trial method to do this but its has been a  long time i am stuck at it .Is there any systematic way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: Think of rotations.

Comment: in $R^2, T^2$ is sometimes called a half rotation. if $T^2$ is half rotation, what is $T?$

Comment: Extra credit if you find one for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @Callus can you suggest something ?

Comment: @Callus i dont think there is any for R^3 case

Comment: Correct.  You can only find one for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n$ even.

Comment: @Callus but what is reason ? I made wild guess

Comment: I don't have a rigorous geometric reason, actually.  Algebraically, the characteristic polynomial is odd degree with non-zero constant term ( because $T$ is invertible ), so it has a non-zero real solution, which means a non-zero real eigenvalue, so $T$ fixes a vector $v$.

Comment: @Callus it will have a non zero real value ,but how and what do you mean by t fixes a vector v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20624/discussion-between-callus-and-tomb-raider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's comment is bull on the money. Take for example

$$T\binom xy=\binom{-y}x$$

which comes from considering the rotation matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&\!\!-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac\pi2&-\sin\frac\pi2\\\sin\frac\pi2&\cos\frac\pi2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: can you  please explain how have you choosed example  here ? How should i think about this

Comment: Think, as said, of rotations: $\;T^2v= -v\;$ is a rotation of half a circle, so $\;T\;$ is half of half a rotation or quarter of a circle,  say a rotation of $\;\frac\pi2\;$ radians.

Comment: Means first (1,0) becomes (0,1) and then becomes (-1,0)  and which is negative of original coordinate .Am i thinking right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You're thinking more linear algebra (and that's fine!), I was going more on geometry.

Comment: If question would have been T^{2} = T , how would i do then except identity transformation

Comment: What about half a circle rotation?

Comment: oh yes i see now thanks .Are their charatersitics specific of reflection and rotation wwith which i can identify in future

Comment: Talking of non-trivial isometries, rotation (in an angle different from a multiple of $\;2\pi\;$) has one unique fixed point, whereas a reflection has one whole straight line as fixed points.